# Trying to abstract code out into a library, but my code isn't working and I do not know why

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to make a library that I can reuse over and over to speed up my development, add to new projects if I wish. Basically I want to build an abstraction layer. Can someone show me how I would do that and why this this portion of code:

```
  if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(enableCamera)]) {
        BOOL enabled;
        enabled = [self.delegate enableCamera];
        if (enabled == YES) {
            [self enableCameraMethod];

        }
```

does not get called?

HERES MY CODE BELOW:

library.h:

```
@protocol usesCamera <NSObject>
@optional
-(BOOL)enableCamera;
@end

@interface Library : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <usesCamera> delegate;
-(void)enableCameraMethod;
@end
```

library.m

```
#import "Library.h"

@implementation Library

- (id) init
{
if (self = [super init]) {        
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(enableCamera)]) {
        BOOL enabled;
        enabled = [self.delegate enableCamera];
        if (enabled == YES) {
            [self enableCameraMethod];

        }
    }
    return (self);

}
}

-(void)enableCameraMethod {
NSLog(@"Implement my camera method here");
}
@end
```

UIViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Library.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <usesCamera>

@end
```

UIViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Library.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *myVC;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(BOOL)enableCamera {
return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

Library *myLibrary = [[Library alloc] init];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

did you set your delegate for myLibrary instance in your ViewController class.
you have to do something like this:

> ```
> Library *myLibrary = [[Library alloc] init];
> myLibrary.delegate = self;
> ```

As init is called before setting the delegate, so it might not worked, instead of defining the logic in init function create another method and call this method after setting the delegate.